# How To Hide Filters On Specific Categories with WooCommerce Products Filter(WOOF)

Tags: plugins, woocommerce-offtopic, e-commerce

I am trying to put filters on products categories and I tried WOOF-WooCommerce Products Filter on wordpress and I saw that the filters that I created on a specific category are sticked and on the other categories which I want to have different filters. Do you know how can I fix that with this plugin or can you recommend me a plugin that supports that feature or if it is possible in any way?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to use my plugin [WOOF by Category](https://wordpress.org/plugins/woof-by-category/). It was developed exactly for this task.

Comment: Do I use this seperately or In merge with the plugin that I have already installed?

Comment: You have to use it together with WooCommerce and WOOF. My plugins requires them to be installed and activated.

Comment: Ok This worked fine. You did a great job thank you!!!!!!